# Recent Activities in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to implement a StackOverflow-style Recent Activities page?

I have a Gallery with user's photos and I want them to be notified when **other** users comment or vote their photos.

Should I create a new table which contains recent activities (updated whenever a user posts a comment or votes) or should I simply use a MySQL query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer is : it depends. If you only need most recent activities and don't need to keep track of activities, or a full 'activity feed' feature, SQL is the way to go. but if you see the need to do a full activity feed kind thing, You can create a model for it.

We did a activity stream recently on our project. Here is how we modeled it

```
Class Activity
   belongs_to :user_activities # all the people that cares about the activity
   belongs_to :actor, class_name='user' # the actor that cause the activity

   belongs_to :target, :polymorphic => true # the activity target(e.g. if you vote an answer, the target can be the answer )
   belongs_to :subtarget, :polymorphic => true # the  we added this later since we feel the need for a secondary target, e.g if you rate an answer, target is your answer, secondary target is your rating. 

   def self.add(actor, activity_type, target, subtarget = nil)
     activity = Activity.new(:actor => actor, :activity_type => activity_type, :target => target, :subtarget => subtarget)
     activity.save!
     activity
   end 
end
```

in the answer_controller we do

```
Class AnswersController
    def create
        ...
        Activity.add(current_user, ActivityType::QUESTION_ANSWERED, @answer)
        ...
    end
end
```

To get a recent activity list from a user we do

```
@activities = @user.activities
```

Comment: Agreed. I would start with SQL queries at first and if that gets too complex, has poor performance, or doesn't seem to fit your needs then make an Activity model.

Comment: To avoid tainting models with this sort of Activity logging, I recommend Rails Observers:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html

Answer (score 2):

This has been written up into a great article which shows the full use of AR, Observers and gives the migration you will need.

http://mickeyben.com/blog/2010/05/23/creating-an-activity-feed-with-rails/

[Observers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html) save you cluttering your models with this information so as well as adding activities you can send emails or whatever else you need to do.

Comment: Right link: http://mickeyben.com/blog/2010/05/23/creating-an-activity-feed-with-rails/