# Rails 3 social networking app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'am figuring out how the build a social network kind of site in Rails. In my site I've a User model. User can add photos, videos, text messages, events etc. Al these kind of updates are stringed together via a polymorphic association to the model Update.

Now for example a certain user follows 10 other users. What is the best way to created an overview of all the updates from the users that this certain user follows.

Answer (score 0):

This post may help. It saves all the activities using the model in a table and then simply draws on them to create the activity stream.

[Recent Activities in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277869/recent-activities-in-ruby-on-rails)

This gem may also be of some use - looks like it largely does the job for you.

https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity